# Shared connection apparently lost in Finder ("connect as..." shown and not working) but still accessible when mounted directly

Tags: finder, network, mount, sharing

I have set up a new Mac Mini M1 computer with macOS Ventura (latest release) as a file server. I have created shared only users and I can mount the shared folders on the connected macs. They get properly shown first in the list after clicking on the Mac Mini file server on the Finder's sidebar. But after some time (10 hours in general), the shared items disappear from the list and instead it shows "connect as" in the right upper side. Clicking on that does not trigger a user/password field at all or refreshed the mounted volumes. However, if I connect to the server via Finder menu directly the share is available and gets mounted but not shown either in the list. Here is a screenshot what I am talking about:

[image: Shared folder is mounted (in sidebar) but sharing overview is empty]

I have read a lot of network issues coming up with macOS Ventura but I didn't find any fix on that. Only a server reboot fixes it. I have tested it with two Macs an both show the same behavior after the same time.

Is there a trick to get it to work? I have already tried a clean install of both the server and one of the clients without success! For a A/B test I specifically created the `/etc/nsmb.conf` file with the following content but with no effect at all:

```
[default]
# Use NTFS streams if supported
streams=yes
# Soft mount by default
soft=yes
# Disable signing due to macOS bug
signing_required=no
# Disable directory caching
dir_cache_off=yes
# Lock negotiation to SMB3 only
# 7 == 0111  SMB 1/2/3 should be enabled
# 6 == 0110  SMB 2/3 should be enabled
# 4 == 0100  SMB 3 should be enabled
# 2 ==   SMB2 only
# protocol_vers_map= choose  2 or 4
protocol_vers_map=4
# Turn off notifications
notify_off=yes

# SMB Negotiation (normal, smb1_only, smb2_only, smb3_only)
smb_neg=smb3_only

# File IDs are legacy compatibility elements for AFP and are not supported by SMB.
file_ids_off=yes
```

Do you have any ideas on that?

Thanks,
Sven